# Counselor for children at youth summer camp

Tags: nouns

I am looking for a fine translation on a recent activity of mine. I worked in a youth summer camp with children aged 7-15.

Deepl.com suggests that I was a "counselor" for children. This does not sound quite exact for me. None of the other suggestions of Deepl.com, Linguee.com and other online dictionaries fit in my eyes.

Is there a better translation for my activity?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What did your work with the children entail? Simple entertainment, sporting activity, general care, washing, dressing, supervising?

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary.  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/counselor Were you a children's supervisor at a camp? Are you writing for a American readership?

Comment: My job contained simple entertainment, sporting activity and supervising. It was not about caring, washing etc. Is there a different word choice for American and English readership?

Answer (score 1):

The position is commonly referred to as a **camp counselor**.

Since you already used the words "camp" and "counselor" in your question, you probably know what they mean, and I think the only thing you didn't realize is that you can put them together.

English speakers understand that "camp counselor" is not the same as "counselor" and that you are not claiming to be a psychiatrist or medical professional.